# How to open a popup window in PyQt4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to make an about popup window in my application made in Python 3 and PyQt4. So far I made a signal that is connected to `self.aboutWindow()`.

I have a `Ui_Mainwindow` class. I'm guessing I have to make a new class and connet it to `self.aboutWindow` funcion but I don't know how to do that.

So far I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838890/python-pyqt-popup-window), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410152/pyqt-on-click-open-new-window), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074195/displaying-pop-up-windows-in-python-pyqt4), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217878/multiple-windows-in-pyqt4) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442128/multiple-windows-in-pyqt4).

Here is my (not so good but working) code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from os import system, chdir
from time import sleep
from subprocess import Popen
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)




class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    global x
    x = 0
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow, parent=None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self)
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(261, 390)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(261, 390))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(261, 390))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("./icon.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(261, 390))
        self.centralwidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(261, 390))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.action = QtGui.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.action.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(104, 60, 91, 22))
        self.action.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("action"))
        self.action.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.action.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.action.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.action.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 221, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 60, 51, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 241, 191))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox"))
        self.selectTime = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.selectTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 82, 17))
        self.selectTime.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("selectTime"))
        self.buttonGroup_2 = QtGui.QButtonGroup(MainWindow)
        self.buttonGroup_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonGroup_2"))
        self.buttonGroup_2.addButton(self.selectTime)
        self.selectDate = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.selectDate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 82, 17))
        self.selectDate.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("selectDate"))
        self.buttonGroup_2.addButton(self.selectDate)
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(116, 60, 61, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
        self.relativeTime = QtGui.QTimeEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.relativeTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 61, 22))
        self.relativeTime.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("relativeTime"))
        self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 140, 21, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
        self.dateTime = QtGui.QDateTimeEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.dateTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 140, 111, 22))
        self.dateTime.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dateTime"))
        self.forceCheck = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.forceCheck.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 81, 21))
        self.forceCheck.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("forceCheck"))
        self.forceCheck.stateChanged.connect(self.changeText)
        self.startButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.startButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 300, 71, 23))
        self.startButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("startButton"))
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.label_5 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 330, 251, 20))
        self.label_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_5"))
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_6 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 360, 261, 20))
        self.label_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_6"))
        self.label_6.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.dateTime.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        self.about = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.about.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 0, 21, 21))
        self.about.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("about"))
        self.about.clicked.connect(self.aboutWindow)
        global tim
        global act
        global forc
        tim = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        tim = str(tim.hour()) + ":" + str(tim.minute())
        act = "Shut Down"
        forc = ""
        self.label_3.setEnabled(False)
        self.relativeTime.setEnabled(False)
        self.label_4.setEnabled(False)
        self.dateTime.setEnabled(False)
        self.selectTime.toggled.connect(self.greyOut2)
        self.selectDate.toggled.connect(self.greyOut1)
        self.action.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.changeText)
        self.dateTime.dateTimeChanged.connect(self.changeText)
        self.relativeTime.timeChanged.connect(self.changeText)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Auto Shutdown", None))
        self.action.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Shut Down", None))
        self.action.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Restart", None))
        self.action.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Go to boot menu", None))
        self.action.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Hibernate", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Please chose an action and then a time for it.", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Action:", None))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Time Schedule", None))
        self.selectTime.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Relative Time", None))
        self.selectDate.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exact Time", None))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "From now", None))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "On", None))
        self.forceCheck.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Force Action", None))
        self.startButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start", None))
        self.about.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "?", None))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Your computer will " + act + " in ", None))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow",  tim + forc, None))
        self.startButton.setEnabled(False)


    def greyOut1(self): #selectDate on
        self.label_3.setEnabled(False)
        self.relativeTime.setEnabled(False)
        self.label_4.setEnabled(True)
        self.dateTime.setEnabled(True)
        self.startButton.setEnabled(True)

    def greyOut2(self): #selectTime on
        self.label_3.setEnabled(True)
        self.relativeTime.setEnabled(True)
        self.label_4.setEnabled(False)
        self.dateTime.setEnabled(False)
        self.startButton.setEnabled(True)
    def changeText(self):
        if self.selectDate.isChecked():
            global forc
            if self.forceCheck.isChecked():
                forc = " (Force)"
            else:
                forc = ""

            act = self.action.currentText()
            tim = self.dateTime.dateTime()
            timm = tim.time()
            dat = tim.date()
            timee = str(dat.day()) + "." + str(dat.month()) + "." + str(dat.year()) + " " + str(timm.hour()) + ":" + str(timm.minute())
            self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Your computer will " + act + " at ", None))
            self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", timee + " " + forc,None))
        else:
            if self.forceCheck.isChecked():
                forc = "(Force)"
            else:
                forc = ""

            act = self.action.currentText()
            tim = self.relativeTime.time()
            now = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
            hr = now.hour() + tim.hour()
            mn = now.minute() + tim.minute()
            timee = str(hr) + ":" + str(mn)
            self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Your computer will " + act + " at ", None))
            self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", timee + forc,None))

    def start(self):
        global x
        if x == 0:
            x = 1
            palette = QtGui.QPalette()
            palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Foreground,QtCore.Qt.darkGreen)
            self.label_5.setPalette(palette)
            self.label_6.setPalette(palette)
            self.startButton.setText("Stop")
            self.label_3.setEnabled(False)
            self.relativeTime.setEnabled(False)
            self.label_4.setEnabled(False)
            self.dateTime.setEnabled(False)
            self.action.setEnabled(False)
            self.selectTime.setEnabled(False)
            self.selectDate.setEnabled(False)
            self.forceCheck.setEnabled(False)

            global f
            global t
            global s
            if self.forceCheck.isChecked():
                f = " /f"

            else:
                f = ""

            if self.action.currentText() == "Shut Down":
                s = "/s"

            elif self.action.currentText() == "Restart":
                s = "/r"
            elif self.action.currentText() == "Go to boot menu":
                s = "/o"
            elif self.action.currentText() == "Hibernate":
                s = "/h"

            if self.selectTime.isChecked():
                tim = self.relativeTime.time()
                now = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()

                timm = int(tim.hour())
                tinn = int(tim.minute())
                hsec = timm * 60
                hsec = hsec * 60
                msec = tinn * 60
                t = msec + hsec
                chdir(".")
                Popen("shutdwn " + s + " /t " + str(t) + f)
            if self.selectDate.isChecked():

                tim = self.dateTime.dateTime()
                now = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime()
                t = tim.toTime_t() - now.toTime_t()
                Popen("shutdwn " + s + " /t " + str(t) + f)




        else:
            x = 0
            palette = QtGui.QPalette()
            palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Foreground,QtCore.Qt.black)
            self.label_5.setPalette(palette)
            self.label_6.setPalette(palette)
            chdir(".")
            Popen("shutdwn /a")
            self.action.setEnabled(True)
            self.selectTime.setEnabled(True)
            self.selectDate.setEnabled(True)
            self.forceCheck.setEnabled(True)    
            self.startButton.setText("Start")   


    def aboutWindow(self):
        pass #Wat do me do here?


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, Python 3.4 (Annaconda3 distibution), PyQt4

Comment: A small tip for the future. Next time you want help do not dump the entire code here. Make [MWE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will be far easier to understand your problem when you have a MWE and help you out.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are correct when you say your code is working.  So you must have a button labeled "about" and you want a pop-up window to open when you click it, right?  You already created an event handler named aboutWindow, so the easiest thing is to call QMessageBox.about:

```
def aboutWindow(self):
    QMessageBox.about(self,"Hello",
        "My StackOverflow code was so long that nobody wanted to read it")
```